# Passing a vector in a function

Tags: c++, performance, vector

Good evening. I am trying to decrease the process time for my code and I realize that passing a 2 dimension vector that keeps growing after each loop is increasing the process time. Is there a way to increase access times for a vector or should I consider a new container(ie list, deque, etc.)
Here is a sample of my code:

This is my function :

```
bool MyFunction(std::vector < std::vector <int> > &p_vector2, std::vector <int> &p_vector, int p)
```

`std::vector < std::vector <int> > &p_vector2` grows by 1 vector for every loop.

Thank you.

Comment: The question uses "increase the process time" in multiple places. Do you mean that you want to make your function faster? If so, you should probably re-word the question to make it clearer what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I want to make the function faster. What I noticed is after the 2 dimension vectors contains over 400 vectors, the function takes much more time to process. I tried passing the arguments as reference with & which allowed me to gain a few seconds but my vector is going to contain 10 000 000 vectors therefore I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Are you sure it's not what you are doing in your function that is slowing your code down rather than passing the vector into the function?

Comment: You should still reword the question to make it clearer. :) It's hard to diagnose the problem without seeing the code and some benchmarks. From what I've read in general `vector` tends to be one of the faster of the STL containers. I'd focus on optimizing your algorithm first.

Comment: Basically the function compares 1 vector with 1 vector from the 2 dimensional vector. The comparaison is done extremely fast. What I noticed is there is a massive slow down when the function is loading the 2 dimensional vector as a parameter.

Comment: Are you testing an optimized build? How are you profiling and deciding this is where a hotspot is? What is a massive slowdown?

Comment: So you are only comparing one vector from `p_vector2` with `p_vector`? Why do you need to pass all of `p_vector2` then? Why not just pass the vector you want to compare?

Comment: CPU profiling shows this function as using 94.11%

Comment: I am comparing p_vector with all p_vector2 to verify if p_vector is identical to any of the vector in p_vector2.

Comment: If that function does most of the work in your program it's going to use most of the cpu.  In order to profile you need to track how long that function is taking in cycles or time and track how it changes when you add more data. You also didn't answer whether you are testing an optimized build or not.

Comment: Based on what you are describing, it is most likely your algorithm that is slowing your program down. Passing your vectors by value will create a copy which will take some time (since your vector contains millions of other vectors), so passing by reference like you did before will help slightly. But focus on creating a better algorithm, or use other techniques to speed up your program (e.g. parallel processing).

Comment: Based on "I am comparing p_vector with all p_vector2 to verify if p_vector is identical to any of the vector in p_vector2." you might want to look at a `std::set`

Comment: Show more code.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using resize() method of vector instead of adding one by one through push_back or similar. resize will allocate space beforehand so you don't have to keep allocating new memory for each item.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

Another option to consider is to allocate the sub-vectors before the function call and have the vector of vectors maintain only the pointers. You need to do the objective destruction on your own.

Comment: Actually resize() completely resizes the vector, while reserve() just reserves space in advance without the need of changing the code. and btw, none will result in a significant improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Using a new container won't help unless you use arrays (which makes a completely different story than others).
Your problem can be solved by changing your code to `std::vector < std::vector <int>& > &p_vector2`, but **be careful**; now every new member of your vector isn't a mere copy of something else, but it is the other vector *itself*. So, if your vector is defined in a scope and the scope ends, c++ will simply delete the vector and you will have nothing as a member of your vector(=> runtime error for sure).

I recommend you to use `new std::vector <int>()` every time you want to declare a vector for the use of the parent vector, in this way you have overcome the previous problem but you should then use delete to free the memory or your code will have memory leak.

If I were in your shoes, I would read a little more about pointers and how to use them, as `new` returns a pointer and you probably face difficulties if you don't study further.

Comment: This is a pretty complicated guess based on a function prototype.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any easier solution to solve this problem.

Comment: My point was how can you answer a question when there's no way to know what's going on in the code we cannot see?  There could be many different ways to optimize and/or the method of profiling could be flawed. Your answer is a guess at best.